# ¿Cómo funcionan estas combinaciones en css?

Tags: html, css, css3

Estaba revisando algunas hojas de estilo de un proyecto web de tipo tienda de que estoy trabajando con un compañero, y veo que el utilizó una combinaciones de css que no conozco y no se como funcionan exactamente, son las siguientes:

1. ```
   #tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
       display: block;
   }
   ```
2. ```
   .tabinput:checked + label {
       color: #555;
       border: 1px solid #ddd;
       border-top: 2px solid orange;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
   }
   ```
3. ```
   .nav li > ul {
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
   }
   ```
4. ```
   .panel-default > .panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"] {
       background-color: #eee;
   }
   ```

Lo pregunto por acá por que no se si el lo ha hecho o es que lo ha copiado simplemente y me gustaría poder tener una definición clara y simple del funcionamiento.

Gracias.

Comment: bueno, el lo que esta haciendo en sobre escribir algunos estilos previamente definidos y sus funciones, te recomiendo un curso de basico de CSS que quizas te ayude a entender mejor que hace el [https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2016/10/20-essential-css-tricks-every-designer-should-know/] este quizas sea el mas lioso `tab4:checked `  que es modificar estilos de los eventos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. El operador `~` en CSS es equivalente al selector jQuery `siblings()` que significa elementos hermanos, o sea que tienen el mismo contenedor padre.
2. El operador `+` se aplica al elemento que esta directamente despues del otro.
3. El operador `>` se utiliza para seleccionar elementos que son hijos directos.
4. Los corchetes `[]` se utilizan para seleccionar elementos con una propiedad especifica.

Answer (score 3):

Por si te sirve de ayuda en un futuro, siempre que tengo alguna duda sobre los selectores recurro a está página de **W3C**:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Están todos juntos y ordenados con una breve descripción lo que hace bastante fácil encontrar lo que buscas. Si tienes problemas con el inglés no deberías tener problemas con el google translate ya que son frases cortas.

En castellano tienes otras páginas pero no encontré ninguna donde estén tan comodamente ordenados los selectores:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selector_CSS
http://librosweb.es/libro/css/capitulo_2/selectores_basicos.html
http://librosweb.es/libro/css/capitulo_2/selectores_avanzados.html

Answer (score 2):

El `~` y el `+` son aplicados para los tabs. Te dejo más información acá: 
https://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/

El `>` es para determinar que, las listas contenidas dentro de la clase `.nav`, tengan sombra y además esté a un `.75%` de opacidad.

Y el *4º escenario* es para determinar que color de fondo tiene un panel. 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_panels.asp

Por las clases que están ocupando parece que utilizan la hoja de estilos de bootstrap.

Comment: Tu respuesta es confusa e inexacta, no tiene que ver especificamente con los tabs, son selectores estandar de CSS
El `+` es para los elementos que estén justo despues del primer elemento, al mismo nivel.
El `~`es para los elementos que estén despues del primer elemento, aunque haya elementos entre ellos, siempre que estén al mismo nivel.
El `>`es para los elementos que sean hijos directos, sin un padre intermedio, del primer elemento.

Comment: Esta respuesta no tiene que ver con la naturaleza y uso de los operadores por los que se pregunta. Es desafortunada y puede motivar confusión. Considera la posibilidad de borrarla.